# How do I disable Sequence Number Caching in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework-core

I need a sequential reference number for items.  Normally I would just use an Identity column, but as of SQL 2012 they can jump up to the next 1000 (I'm seeing 1, 2, 1001, 2001, 2002).

Reading up I see suggestions of using a sequence as it's now easy in EF Core 2.1.  Problem is it still has some caching, 50 numbers at a time, so I am now seeing 1, 2, 3, 51, 52.

Looking at the SQL documentation I can see you can disable this caching, there is just no way, that I can see, to do it via the fluent API in EF Core.

Suggestions?

Comment: Added a "brute force" method as a placeholder until something more elegant pops up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious, so I am looking for a more elegant solution but in the meantime ... Perhaps you can get around this "sideways".  Create a table just for this sequencing issue like so:

```
public class mySequence {
    public int sequence {get; set;}
    public bool locked {get; set;}
}
```

Create an index (descending) on sequence.  1) Lock sequence TABLE;  2) Find "next" unlocked sequence #;  3) If none, seed with next X sequence numbers;  4) Lock the "next" sequence #;  5) Unlock Table;  6) Use sequence # in your real data

Have to have exclusive control over *some* resource to mitigate collisions/duplicates.

Hm, more "elegant" solution presents itself...

[Sequences using Fluent API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/sequences)

Comment: Darned if it doesn't do exactly what I mentioned but handles all the grunt work.

Comment: I'm using this Fluent API, but it does not give you control over the cache option on the sequence.  The SQL docs says "When created with the CACHE option, an unexpected shutdown (such as a power failure) may result in the loss of sequence numbers remaining in the cache."  This is occurring for me on dev and it looks bad to the client.  I've had to do the following to get around it "migrationBuilder.Sql("ALTER SEQUENCE x NO CACHE;");"